# How to ensure directory path exists on symlinking in Chef?

Tags: symlink, chef-infra, chef-solo

Creating a symlink in Chef:

```
link "#{node[:tomcat][:home]}/webapps/myface.war" do
  to "/srv/scafandru/current/myface.war"
end
```

fails, since at that time the parent directory is missing on the node.

In the [`link` resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_link.html) I couldn't see any attribute similar to the [`directory` resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_directory.html)'s `recursive true`, so my current approach is to ensure that the directory structure exists by running

```
directory "#{node[:tomcat][:home]}/webapps" do
  recursive true
end
```

right before linking.

Is there any elegant way to encapsulate this behaviour inside the link resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is the best one if you don't want to write code.

If you are willing to have a better solution, you may extend the provider for link to add the recursive attribute.

To do that, you can refer to [opscode documentation](http://wiki.opscode.com/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=7274964) that states:

> **Extending An Existing Provider**
>
> If you'd like to write a LWP that
>   extends another provider class, you can accomplish that as a mixin,
>   which you would then place in a library under the library directory of
>   the cookbook using that extended class.
>
> Your LWRP would then be written to include that library in the
>   provider implementation to get access to the extended core resource.
>   For an example, see the Transmission Cookbook, which includes a
>   `transmission_torrent_file` LWRP that allows you to download a file
>   via the BitTorrent protocol. This `transmission_torrent_file` LWRP are
>   an extension of the existing file and remote_file resources.